# Started React Native With Swift Instead Of Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

So I started a react native app using create-react-native-app and it created a lot of boilerplate code. Android is in `JAVA` which I am fine with. But the iOS is in `Objective-C` and I am more familiar with `Swift`. Is there anything I can do about that? I know most of my code is going to be in `JavaScript` anyways, but just wondering anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not a simple or one command way to convert your iOS code in your React Native project from `Objective-C` to `Swift`. However if you want to write a [Native Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios), which you'll need to `eject from CRN` or start a new project with `react-native init`, you can write new code in Swift.

You might also be interested in this [post](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-and-objective-c-interoperability-2add8e6d6887) on how to bridge `Swift` and `Objective-C` code. Basically when you create a new swift file you need to make sure to select “Create Bridging Header” when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is not that clear. But lemme say this if you wanted to work on cross platform then react native is a good choice to that if you wanted to use javscript. Regarding on your question which is , lemme quote "But the IOS is in Objective C" which is you're wrong you can write an iOS native using both objective c , even c and c++ , ..and swift  which you say your familiar with and if you're avoiding objective c then you can write iOS app purely in swift. Hope that helps.

## Tips

```
1 for cross platform - and you want js (react native)
2. cross platform and you wanted to use c# (Xamarine)
3. iOS app which is native (Swift or objective c) or both
4. hybrid , you can try framework like ionic, cordova etc.
5. let us include android , you can use java(kotlin
```

Comment: I strongly feel like you don't truly understand what I am talking about. See, when I use create-react-native-app in the command line, it creates boilerplate code. At the root level of that directory is an android folder, iOS folder and the index javascript file. The code in the android folder is in Java. The code in iOS is in objective C. What I want to know is if there is a nice easy way for me to use that command or a different one to initialize my react native project where the iOS folder code is in Swift instead of objective C.

Comment: What you wanted to use? do you want to use react native , right?

Comment: if you are using  create-react-native-app command in generating project then this is purety react native and the language is react js. You don't have to worry about the other files that was generated.

Comment: swift and objective c has nothing to do with react native.

Comment: please refer to this https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/516 . thank you.

Comment: really I don't have to worry about the other files that were generated? because I went through a few tutorials to do some things. One of those things was making a splash screen. I still have to touch the iOS xib file and android. while in that situation, switft or java doesn't matter much, I can imagine scenarios where I would need to go back to native code. For example creating a package in native code to be used in react native.

Comment: so what is your focus ? react native?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert swift to objective c or objective c to swift.

There are bunch of options for that, If you want to use javascript for converting than use obj2swift.js: https://github.com/okaxaki/objc2swift.

If you want to convert your code online than you can use online language converter like swiftify:
https://swiftify.com/#/converter/code/